# What is the theoretical max number of concurrent (simultaneous) HTTP connections in a Go server?

Tags: http, concurrency, go

What is the upper limit on the number of concurrent HTTP connections that a very simple server implemented in Go can handle?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The number of concurrent HTTP connections is limited by available memory and by operating system limits.

In Linux, the soft operating system limits - such as the maximum number of open files - can be printed out and changed by using `ulimit`.

In terms of memory, each HTTP connection in a minimal Go HTTP server running on 32-bit Linux consumes **21 KiB** of memory (the source code of this server, compilable with Go version 2013-03-23, is below). On 64-bit Linux, the memory consumption can be expected to be higher.

On a 32-bit system with 1GB of memory available to the server, 21 KiB means that about **50,000** simultaneous connections are possible. This does *not* include memory consumed by the Linux kernel.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

var isClient = flag.Bool("client", false, "Whether to start the HTTP server or the HTTP client")
var N = flag.Int("n", 1000, "Number of concurrent HTTP requests")

var wait = make(chan byte)
var counter = 0
var reachedN = make(chan byte)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "some text")
    counter++
    if counter == *N {
        reachedN <- 0
    }
    <-wait // Block this goroutine
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if *N <= 0 {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "invalid number of goroutines")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    if *isClient {
        // Initiate N http connections
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        for i := 0; i < *N; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(ii int) {
                _, err := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:12345")
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "client %d: %s\n", ii, err)
                    os.Exit(1)
                }
                wg.Done()
            }(i)
        }
        wg.Wait()
    } else {
        runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1) // No concurrency

        // Read MemStats
        var m0 runtime.MemStats
        runtime.ReadMemStats(&m0)

        go func() {
            <-reachedN // Wait until there are *N concurrent requests

            // Read MemStats
            var m1 runtime.MemStats
            runtime.ReadMemStats(&m1)

            fmt.Printf("Number of HTTP connections:        %d\n", *N)
            fmt.Printf("Memory consumption per connection: %.2f bytes\n", float64(m1.Sys-m0.Sys)/float64(*N))
            os.Exit(1)
        }()

        http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":12345", nil)
        if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "server: %s\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be kept in mind that while all ports are just ports, the low group are considered reserved. The impact of messing with anything under 1024 may break something unexpected. For instance, you've opened port 80 to accept requests, but you can't accept any because you're sending data out of it.

Comment: Incognito, i like ur comments, but can u please explain a little bit more? Is the 1024 in bytes or KB? If i am sending http requests out from a 64-bit unix server, what's the maximum i can send concurrently? Thanks!

Comment: @Atom The code no longer compiles on go v1.0.3 as of 3/23/13. Can you fix it?

Comment: @trillions It's not a size. You have 65535 ports on a Linux system. The first 1024 of them are what you can call "privileged ports". Usually you need to be root to listen on them, and they're "reserved" usually for core types of processes.